# The necessity of omitting/adding “zu” before an infinitive

Tags: infinitive

I have seen the following sentences:

> Es ist besser, nicht den Kopf zu verlieren.
>
> Hör auf mich zu schlagen.

I would make the first sentence with simpler: *Verlieren* simply means *to lose.* So wouldn’t *den Kopf verlieren* already mean what I need? Why add *zu* here?
The same goes for the second sentence.

What is the rule of thumb to decide when to enter/omit *zu* in these contexts?

Comment: What is the question here? Do you want to know if "Es ist besser, nicht den Kopf verlieren" is a well-formed German sentence? No, it isn't. You need the *zu*. It is irrelevant that by convention you translate "verlieren" by "to lose" (as "to" is used in English as a marker for infinitive)

Comment: You can't omit the "to" in "It's better not *to* lose your head." either. As Christian said, it is only by convention that the "to" is part of the lexicon entry in English and the "zu" isn't in German.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add "zu" in order to complete your thought about losing.

That's because the "infinitive" is "to lose" only in English. German has an infinitive form that ends in "en," verlieren. There is no "to" in that version.

When the German uses zu in "zu verlieren," the context is "in order/not *to lose*." The italicized part is NOT the infinitive "to lose."

The reason is that "to" forms part of the infinitive in English but not in German. In English, you don't need a second "to" for (in order.not) to lose. But in German, you need a "zu" because it was never part of the infinitive.

Comment: I'm a little confused. If I said "I want something to (to = in order to) eat" then that would be "Ich will etwas zu essen". Zu makes sense here.
But how is "in order to" any relevant in "It is better not to lose one's head"?

Comment: @user268569: I'd consider that the "gerund" form, not the infintive. The construction would be,Ich will etwas zuM Essen"

Comment: So in conclusion. to lose would be "verlieren" but once we introduce a object noun to go along with it, one must always add zu with it?
To lose - verlieren
To lose one's head - Den kopf ZU verlieren.

The same way
To kill - töten
To kill someone - Jemanden ZU toten?

Can you give me any reference be it a book or a website on how to decide on adding/omitting "zu"?

Much appreciated

Comment: @user268569: In your examples, you need "zu" for all the phrases with purpose or direction or end result. (To lose one's head. To kill someone.) You don't need zu for the "standalone" verbs. (To kill. To lose.)

Comment: @user268569 No, one must not always add "zu" if there is an object noun. The standard translation of "to kill someone" is "jemanden töten". "I want to kill someone" = "Ich will jemanden töten". No "zu". "Zu" is only added in special cases (see Janka's answer).

Comment: I see, thanks for the explanation. But had I said "Es ist besser, nicht jemanden zu töten" would that be correct? It seems to be the same structure of the original, doesn't it?

Comment: @user268569: That is what I would call a "purpose" clause that requires "zu."

Comment: @user268569 Replace "nicht jemanden" ("not someone") with "niemanden" ("noone") and then it is correct, yes.

Comment: @user268569: May I ask you for an upvote, for the all work that I (and others) did on this thread? You seem to have learned something from it.

Comment: Sure. I appreciate your explanations

Comment: This answer is wrong. There is no final component (*in order to*) with *zu* plus infinitive in the above sentences (as can easily be seen by translating them into English); rather, *zu* plus infinitive is used for subject and object clauses.

Answer (score 8):

There are many uses for the infinitive in German, sometimes with *zu*, sometimes without it. To keep it simple, I sum up the three cases with *zu* for someone who knows English:

First, sometimes when English uses its gerund, which German lacks:

> Zu lesen fällt mir leicht.

*Reading comes easy to me.*

BUT as German speakers adore nouns, the alternative with a noun made from an infinitive is far more common. (Note the caps on *Lesen*.)

> (Das) Lesen fällt mir leicht.

Second, anywhere English uses its to-infinitive:

> Sie gab mir eine deutsche Zeitung zu lesen.

*She gave me a German newspaper to read.*

Third, in a special clause: the **Infinitivsatz**. That clause is a very common replacement for an **Objektsatz** if its subject is identical to that of the main clause.

> **Sie** verbrachte den Nachmittag damit, dass **sie** die Zeitung las. (Objektsatz)
>
> Sie verbrachte den Nachmittag damit, die Zeitung zu lesen. (Infinitivsatz)

*She spent the afternoon reading the newspaper.*

If you use the *Objektsatz* instead of the *Infinitivsatz*, German speakers would automatically assume the subject has changed and are puzzled if it hasn't.

This third case is uncommon to English speakers but you can easily spot it because it's used in a lot of cases where English uses its to-infinitive or its gerund. See the other two cases, remember you have to place a comma, and –unlike English– it's a clause of its own.

Comment: The comma is not always obligatory.

Comment: The English infinitive is *to read*. I am unaware of English having *to + infinitive* constructions: ‘She gave me a newspaper to to read’?

Comment: It's a bit of nitpicking, isn't it? I've edited to+infinitive into to-infinitive.

Comment: The second *Sie* in bold typeface should be in lower case, however.

Comment: Ah, yes. Thanks.

Comment: @Jan The English infinitive is not *to* plus verb. That's merely what Germans are taught in school. Examples of bare infinitives: *He can read*, *he does read*.

Comment: @DavidVogt That form is called the *stem form*.