# zu+infintiv - Not after gehen and kommen?

Tags: preposition

Our teacher told us, that beside modal verbs, you need to use *zu* + *infinitive* for example:

> Es ist schwer, Deutsch zu lernen.

*ist* is not a modal verb and this is why we use *zu*.

But I saw these sentences recently:

> Ich gehe Essen kaufen.

Isn't it suppose to be *zu kaufen*?

> Er kommt Dan besuchen.

Isn't is suppose to be *zu besuchen*?

Is there any rule when you do not need *zu*?

Comment: I can't answer your question, but the sentences without *zu* are correct as is. However, you could use *zu* in these sentences: "Er kommt, Dan zu besuchen." This is an older form of *um... zu* and isn't used often.

Comment: Those sentences sound to me like colloquial German, and usual rules of grammar wouldn't apply to that. _Ich gehe aus, um etwas zum Essen zu kaufen_, or _Er kommt, um Dan zu besuchen_. These of course are rather long-winded (esp the first one), so are often abbreviated in everyday usage.

Answer (score 6):

*Our teacher told us, that beside modal verbs, you need to use zu+infinitiv*

That's … unfortunately not too helpful, as German makes no sharp distinction between modal verbs and others. Aside from the pretty common modal verbs *müssen*, *können*, *dürfen*, *sollen*, *wollen*, *mögen*, *möchten*, a number of other verbs may also be used as modals.

**Gehen**, **kommen**, **sehen**, **hören**, **lassen** are common "second-tier" modal verbs.

> Sie geht arbeiten.
>
> Er kommt kochen.
>
> Sie sehen ihn fallen.
>
> Ich hörte sie spielen.
>
> Sie lässt ihn essen.

In general, verbs of movement, cognition, and exercise are hot candidates for modals:

> Er fuhr arbeiten.
>
> Ich fühle es kribbeln.
>
> Sie übt radfahren.

---

You asked about a rule *when not to use zu*. The question has to be when to use *zu*. I've answered this question already [here](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/39346/the-necessity-of-omitting-adding-zu-before-an-infinitive/39352#39352).

Comment: Beim letzten Beispiel widerspricht mein Sprachgefühl: "Sie übt Radfahren" oder "Sie übt, Rad zu fahren". Ebenso: "Sie übt Schreiben" oder "Sie übt, zu schreiben". Ebenso mit "lernen".