# Insertion of -zu- in German verbs

Tags: translation, german-to-english

How does "zu" change the meaning of the verb when it is inserted in between a word?

A specific example from a 18th century paper:

> In der Tat gelang es nicht, auf dem Spectrum eines glühenden Platindrahtes oder des Drummondschen Lichtes die dunklen Natriumlinien durch die Leuchtgasflamme **hervorzugerufen**, in die Kochsalz gebracht war; aber es gelang mit der Flamme von wässrigem Alkohol, der Kochsalz enthielt.

In the dictionary, *hervorrufen* is listed, which means to "cause"? What is *zu* serving here?

Google Translation looks pretty good (as it makes scientific sense):

> The absorption of the sodium vapor will be all the more perceptible, the lower its luminosity, that is, the lower its temperature. In fact, on the spectrum of a glowing platinum wire or the Drummond light, the dark sodium lines were not succeeded by the luminous gas flame into which salt was brought; but it succeeded with the flame of aqueous alcohol containing saline.

Comment: *hervorzugerufen* looks like an error. It is certainly not current German. That would be *hervorzurufen*. Perhaps in the 18th century *hervorgerufen* was a proper verb.

Comment: Rudy is right, it has to read *hervorzurufen* in contemporary German. Well, why not *hervorrufen*? Because it's a *zu-Infinitiv*, not a plain one. I have written something about its use a while ago: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/39346/the-necessity-of-omitting-adding-zu-before-an-infinitive/39352#39352 It's the third case here, the **Infinitivsatz**.

Comment: Also *dunkeln* has to read *dunklen*. Typo.

Comment: @Janka Only true today, 18th century German was quite different and far less strict. Even late 19th century Brockhaus Konversationslexikon is quite happy with *dunkeln*, *größern* etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't change the meaning at all, but is just used in some grammatical contexts automatically (like *to* in English). In this example the reason is the verb *gelingen* in the main clause, which requires this construction in the subordinate one.

(It's inserted in the middle of the verb in this case because *hervorrufen* is separable. Otherwise it would just be *zu* + infinitive.)