# Modalverb im Präsens mit zwei Verben im Infinitiv

Tags: sentence-structure, grammaticality, verb-usage, modal-verb, infinitive

> Einige Männer ***wollen*** die Welt einfach ***brennen sehen***.
>
> Ich ***muss*** ***einkaufen gehen***.
>
> Er ***will*** nachher ***einkaufen gehen***.
>
> Sie ***möchten*** Musik ***spielen lernen***.

All this sentences are constructed the same way.

They all have a conjugated modal verb in present simple in position 2, and two verbs in their infinitive form at the end.

Are these sentences correct ? Can we use two consecutive infinitives with a modal-verb in present simple ?

or maybe we should add a "zu" before the last verb as in this examples :

> Er *will* nachher *einkaufen* **zu** *gehen*.
>
> Einige Männer *wollen* die Welt einfach *brennen* **zu** *sehen*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first four example sentences are correct. The row of infinitives may be even longer:

> Ich muss einkaufen gehen können.

*I have to be able to go shopping.*

> Sie möchten nicht Baseball spielen lernen müssen.

*They don't like to have to learn (how) to play baseball.*

> Sie müssen aber spielen lernen können wollen dürfen.

That last one is a bit artificial, though.

---

A while ago, I wrote an [answer when to use *zu+Infinitive*.](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/39346/the-necessity-of-omitting-adding-zu-before-an-infinitive/39352#39352)

Modals aren't one of those cases, I have to correct myself.