# Can Prepositions be used as conjunctions in german

Tags: preposition, conjunction

While going through the following sentence I got confused about the structure of sentence after coma. Why verb is coming at last place?

"Die großen Leute haben mir geraten, mit den Zeichnungen von offenen oder geschlossenen Riesenschlangen aufzuhören"

Is it that "mit" is acting as subordinating conjunction

Comment: No, it's not acting as a conjunction. It's *standing at the position* where you usually find subordinating conjunctions, but that's not the same thing. The subordinated clause doesn't have a conjunction - the *mit* is just a regular preposition that happens to come first in the subclause.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Die großen Leute haben mir geraten, mit den Zeichnungen von offenen oder geschlossenen Riesenschlangen auf**zu**hören.

I don't question the meaning of this sentence. It's grammatically okay, though *mit dem Zeichnen* is more idiomatic than *mit den Zeichnungen*.

I've marked the tricky detail you are looking for. The **zu** in *aufzuhören*. This is the *zu-Infinitiv* of the verb *aufhören*, and thus, this is an infinitive clause. These clauses aren't lead by a conjunction.

---

Infinitive clauses are a special type of clause German has. It replaces an object clause when the subject in the object clause and the main clause are the same.

> **Ich** hatte irgendwann damit angefangen, dass **ich** Riesenschlangen zeichne.

Here, *zeichne* is a finite verb in an object clause lead by *dass*. The whole clause is an object to the finite verb *hatte angefangen* in the main clause. Both subjects are the same, *ich*. So German speakers instead say:

> Ich hatte irgendwann damit angefangen, Riesenschlangen zu zeichnen.

Instead of a finite verb, we now have a *zu-Infinitiv*. The subject is gone, as well as the conjunction.

Back to your example. With an equivalent object clause, it reads

> Die großen Leute haben mir geraten, **dass ich** mit den Zeichnungen von offenen oder geschlossenen Riesenschlangen **aufhöre**.

In the rare case of subject clauses, infinitive clauses can also replace those:

> Es ist doch selbstverständlich, dass ich dir helfe.
>
> Es ist doch selbstverständlich, dir zu helfen.

---

How to spot those special clauses? Look for the **zu**, either in front of an infinitive, or between prefix and stem.

CAVEAT: There are a few verbs with a *zu* in their normal infinitive, e.g. *zusammenzucken*. The *zu-Infinitiv* of that verb is *zusammen**zu**zucken*.

Comment: Vielen Dank für die Erklärung!

Comment: Nichts zu danken.

Comment: The zu-Infinitiv is often used in places where in English one would use a gerund. Compare *Die Leute haben mir geraten, mit dem Zeichnen aufzuhören* / *People advised me to stop drawing.*

Comment: Well … no. In your example, the gerund is *drawing*. The German *zu-Infinitiv* *aufzuhören* drops in where English has its infinitive *to stop*. I've made a short list of usages of the *zu-Infinitiv* here: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/39346/the-necessity-of-omitting-adding-zu-before-an-infinitive/39352#39352