# Use of zu + infinitve as noun

Tags: translation, infinitive

I’m going through the book “German Short Stories for Beginners”. In the second story I came across the following sentence:

> Dort Baden zu gehen ist fast wie am Meer.

The question is: Why is *zu* used for *Baden zu gehen*?

Can *zu* signal noun use for infinitives?

Comment: Check this answer (the accepted answer is nonsense): https://german.stackexchange.com/a/39352/35111

Comment: Since you are using Enlgish, perhaps, consider the same sentence in English: "To go bathing there is almost the same as at the sea".

Answer (score 1):

The sentence contains a mistake. It should be written with a lowercase b, i.e. [baden gehen](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/baden). However, the *zu* is used with *gehen*, so even if baden was used as a noun, it wouldn't change anything here. Thus

> Dort baden zu gehen.

is the correct way. However you can make it a noun, with an additional zu and an article (indicating it indeed is treated as a noun here):

> Dorthin zum Baden zu gehen ist schön.

Comment: Interesting. @Janka makes a case here: https://german.stackexchange.com/a/39352/35111 that one can use capitalized `Baden`

Comment: Even _dort baden gehen ist schön_ would be grammatical. But in this case I have to admit that I have no idea whether _baden_ should be capitalized. Or _gehen_, even.

Comment: Both are verbs and should be written lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

"baden zu gehen" is the infinitive construction. Such type of sentence construction is basically used for separable verbs or to separate the verbs coming one after the other.
As rightly stated in the previous answer, baden should be written with small 'b'.

Then the sentence would make complete sense: Dort baden zu gehen ist fast wie am Meer